# Special letter behaviour problem?

Tags: sql-server-2012, xml, dynamic-sql, cast, unicode

I asked question in very blurry manner because I cannot explain in short sentence what is my problem about.

In general I have a set of procedures which transforms text and XML. Inside the procedures I have a lot of `NVARCHAR` and `XML` variables and a table with `XML` column. Inside my data I have special letters (for example `ò`). When I run all the code the special character disappears and is visible as `?` - which mean that I got `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`.

In general I got everything ok until the final steps. I got `EXEC` which call stored procedure with ad hoc constructed variable of type `NVARCHAR`. I have into a table which contains `XML` field. In this case I got `?`. If I run procedure manually (not in `EXEC INTO`) I got proper symbol.

Any ideas why this happens? 
I checked all variables and they are `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Please, until you set up a verifiable example, this is not clear or too localized

Comment: Have you seen this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816824/unicode-text-gets-corrupted-while-converting-from-xml-data-type-to-nvarchar-in-s

Comment: @JonathanFite, 10x for link. It seems something like my case. I just need to try the solution.

Comment: You checked that all your variables are `nvarchar` but when you use single quotes to delimit the strings, do you always prefix them with `N`? Compare: `SELECT N'', '';`

Comment: Yes, @AaronBertrand. This was fault actually. I did forgot to set `N` before my string when calling procedure. I did not check that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but typically when you have Unicode characters and you end up with question marks or boxes, the problem is actually relatively simple. When you declare a Unicode string with `'single quotes'`, [you need to prefix them with an `N''`](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-unicode). N stands for national, not nvarchar (admittedly, a U prefix - for Unicode -  would have made more sense).

Compare:

```
SELECT Prefix = N'', NoPrefix = '';
```

Results:

```
Prefix      NoPrefix
------      --------
           ??
```

Comment: var day = made;